# Linux Process Lifecycle Timeline Graphing/Visualization

Tags: linux, process, charts, data-visualization

Is there a tool that will monitor the creation and destruction of Linux processes and generate data that would enable me to graph these events with respect to time? Or, alternatively, the tool would itself provide a graph or other visualization?

In other words, I would like to obtain a timeline of process creation/destruction over a certain time period. Other details about process activity, such as CPU utilization, would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lastcomm` command examines the logfile `/var/log/pacct` if process accounting is enabled.

See `man acct`.